# Python find String in XML or *.bat

Tags: python, xml, batch-file

I have a directory that contains both xml and *.bat files. I would like to find and replace the string "-SNAPSHOT" in any xml or *.bat file. I can do this in notepad ++ where I go to Find in Files, enter "-SNAPSHOT" for the Find object, and "pom.xml,*.bat" in the filter type, and it does what I am trying to do. However, I'd like to be able to accomplish the same thing in a python script. What is the best approach for this? Thanks.

Comment: What is your specific problem? What have you tried?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
import os

myfldr = "myfolder\\"
mydir = os.listdir(myfldr)
old = "-SNAPSHOT"
new = "NEW_STRING"


for file in mydir:

    tempdoc = []
    if (".xml" in file) or (".bat" in file):
        path = myfldr + file
        with open(path, "rt") as f:

            for line in f:
                line = line.replace(old, new)
                tempdoc.append(line)

        with open(path, "wt") as f:
            f.writelines(tempdoc)
```